# With ufw, how do I limit SSH from outside, and not from inside?

Tags: firewall, ufw

Using [UFW](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uncomplicated_Firewall), limiting connection attempts for things like SSH is real easy:

```
# ufw limit SSH
```

However, I'd like to limit only the public-facing interface, not the LAN interface. This command does it indiscriminately. Naively, I tried

```
# ufw allow SSH from 192.168.1.0/24
```

but it doesn't like that. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ufw limit in on ethX to any port ssh proto tcp
```

where ethX is the public-facing interface.

https://serverfault.com/questions/270715/ubuntu-ufw-set-a-rule-on-a-per-interface-basis

Comment: This does not work for me using ufw 0.33: "ERROR: Wrong number of arguments".

Comment: @JohannesErnst Must be the wrong syntax then.  Don't have a box with UFW installed to check.  Try: ufw limit in on ethX port 22

Comment: @JohannesErnst I installed UFW quick on a VM to check.  Updated the post with syntax that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always delete all SSH-rules and manually open traffic on port 22 on a specific interface. `sudo ufw allow in on ensX to any port 22`

Where ensX is your local nic.